# ES6 imports in chrome devtools

Tags: angular, reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

Does anyone know how to see es6 imports in chrome devtools in a webpack application? eg. `import {map} from 'lodash'` and in devtools we get `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined` at any breakpoint. This may not be webpack specific.

I've tried tweaking sourcemaps & have never been able to get this working. Exploring both Angular (2+) and React apps, similar experiences.

For minimal replication steps: anyone can easily replicate this with either the angular cli or create-react-app cli tools - create an empty project & start debugging - check an import. However, any javascript web application using ES6 imports should do - ie. if you have a web app, and can see imports defined, then please comment.

For example, from the create-react-app quickstart https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app, simply run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Open, chrome devtools, open app.js, put a breakpoint in `render` and try to inspect `React`.

[image: Debugging scenario]

When referencing lodash above, lodash is a simple example of an npm dependency, installed with `npm install lodash`.

Comment: Is `lodash` an external dependency in your webpack config?

Comment: I can add an example, however, it would simply be reproducing: 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app
https://cli.angular.io
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: @JonasWilms not sure about 'external dependency in webpack config' - however this sounds like it is worth looking into.

Comment: One trick I've just found to get around this: add a property eg. `_ = {map}` to a class, then `this._.map` will be inspect-able at a breakpoint on a class.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I've added a MVCE to the description, ie. run create-create-app, open devtool, inspect for `React` - not defined. Any web app with ES6 should behave the same, however.